# Set location to newly mounted disk image fails in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to run the following code in a function in my script:

```
$result = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $imagepath -PassThru
$driveLetter = ($result | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
Set-Location "$($driveLetter):"
```

But it constantly fails with this error:

```
  Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'G' does not exist.
  At C:\Users\Agent\BuildAgent\scripts\helpers.psm1:35 char:3
  +   Set-Location "$($driveLetter):"
  +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (G:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

But after the script has terminated I can change the drive, no problem.

It might be timing related, but injecting a sleep (even a large one) before setting location, does not help.

Does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: The drive did not exist at the time the PowerShell session started so it is not aware of it. I have a  script that maps a drive and I restart the script so that I can reference the drive letter. If there is a way to refresh the provider live I am not aware of it.

Comment: @Matt that sounds like an answer to me :) I wonder if there's a difference when you exit a method in a module too. I have this part in an imported module, and I have found out that if I start a process on the drive after the method has returned, it works. I have not yet tried to Set-Location after method returns to validate if it is the exit from method or Set-Location vs Start-Process that makes the difference. If any of them.

Answer (score 3):

Let's all up-vote the [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/804580).

Then, I think I have a workaround by manually adding the drive as a new [PSDrive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee176915.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I guess the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet can access the mounted drive even though others can't.

```
$mount = Mount-DiskImage $isoPath -PassThru
$driveLetter = ($mount | Get-Volume).DriveLetter

# Have to use New-PSDrive so other cmdlets in this session can see the new drive
New-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$($driveLetter):\"

// ...do things...

Dismount-DiskImage $mount.ImagePath
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't try this but your command looks odd to me 
Set-Location "$($driveLetter):"

have you tried
Set-Location "$driveLetter:"

without the parens

Comment: That might create an issue since the `:` is used as a [scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) modifier in variable. PowerShell would not interpret this the way you intend. That is why the op has that as a subexpression.